# Group nearby column values in Python Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame with some columns, say 'n' columns and some rows, say 'm' row. I want to group DataFrame rows depending on one column(Column:'x') values, Its not the exact match of column 'x' values. I need to group out nearby values. For example my DataFrame would be like this:

```
      y    yh     x    xw       w   Nxt
0   2987  3129   347  2092  1735.0   501
1   2715  2847   501  1725  1224.0   492
2   2419  2716   490  2196  1704.0   492
3   2310  2373   492   794   302.0   886
4   2309  2370   886  1012   126.0   492
5   2198  2261   497   791   299.0   886
6   2197  2258   886  1010   124.0   492
7   1663  2180   375  1092   600.0  1323
```

In above dataframe difference between column 'x' values is between 20 then i need to group them into a new dataframe and rest of them can be avoided. Here the index=1,2,3,5 rows can be a one group and index=4,6 would be another group, because difference between those rows 'x' column is between 20. My expected output should be three dataframes- `df1`:one holds all grouped rows and `df2`:holds another group of rows and 'df3': rest of the rows as follows:

df1:

```
      y    yh     x    xw       w   Nxt
1   2715  2847   501  1725  1224.0   492
2   2419  2716   490  2196  1704.0   492
3   2310  2373   492   794   302.0   886
5   2198  2261   497   791   299.0   886
```

df2:

```
      y    yh     x    xw       w   Nxt
4   2309  2370   886  1012   126.0   492
6   2197  2258   886  1010   124.0   492
```

df3:

```
    y    yh     x    xw       w   Nxt
0   2987  3129   347  2092  1735.0   501
7   1663  2180   375  1092   600.0  1323
```

I tried with Groupby-apply and groupby-transform but couldn't succeed. It would be great help if any one can help me to get this expected one, thanks in advance.

Comment: The difference between rows 4 and 7 is also less than 20, should these rows also be grouped separately?

Comment: The value of column x at row 0 and 7 are within 20 to each other so should they be in another dataframe? same for row 4 and 6? my question is really, how did you decide that `df1` holds only the group of x value around 500?

Comment: @user2699, Yes those rows can also be grouped separate as another data-frame like df3...

Comment: How do you know the range upto which they can be clubbed together?

Comment: @Ben.T, yes for row 4 and 6 it should be another dataframe df3... for row 0 & 7 i have edited the values, thats type mistake, sorry.

Comment: @JackDaniels range 20 that is fixed one always.

Comment: @ras ok now a question, what do you to do if you have 3 values in x, let's say 400, 415 and 430: they are all within 20 around 415 but 400 and 430 are more than 20 apart?

Comment: @Ben.T hi Ben, generally i will not have values in a range of very less difference, either its between less than 20 or its more than 100-150. To make clear Here i am trying to get pixels from an image and above dataframe is identified pixels of x, y coordinates and width(xw),height(yh).  i want to get nearby 'x' coordinate pixels, so it will have either in range of 20 or difference would be more than 100-150.

Comment: How do we decide what to consider as base? because say there are values 0 20 40 60 80 100. What will be the criteria here?

Comment: @JackDaniels Yes thats the one i was facing how to consider the base one. but here all 0,20,40,60,80,100 will go to one group and next one would be not 120 its 200 or more...

Comment: ok, but I am saying if it is 120, it might be clubbed together, until unless we put a limit on the length of the subset to be chosen from the column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to group the value in the column 'x' within 20, what you can do is using `shift` and create a column named 'group' to locate where all the space between two rows is above 20, once values are sorted by 'x'.

```
df = df.sort_values('x')
df.loc[(df.x.shift() < df.x - 20),'group'] = 1 # everytime the jump betweeen two row is more than 20
# use cumsum, ffill and fillna to complete the column group and have a different number for each one
df['group'] = df['group'].cumsum().ffill().fillna(0)
#if the order of indexes matters, you can here add df = df.sort_index() and the code after is the same
```

With your input, you get:

```
      y    yh    x    xw       w   Nxt  group
0  2987  3129  347  2092  1735.0   501    0.0
7  1663  2180  375  1092   600.0  1323    1.0
2  2419  2716  490  2196  1704.0   492    2.0
3  2310  2373  492   794   302.0   886    2.0
5  2198  2261  497   791   299.0   886    2.0
1  2715  2847  501  1725  1224.0   492    2.0
4  2309  2370  886  1012   126.0   492    3.0
6  2197  2258  886  1010   124.0   492    3.0
```

Now, you can create a list of dataframe for each group when there is more than one row in the group. You need to use `groupby` on 'x', `filter` the group with a length more than 1. At the end, add all the group with a length one as one dataframe:

```
list_df = [df_g for name_g, df_g in df.groupby('group').filter(lambda x: len(x)>1).groupby('group')] +\
            [df.groupby('group').filter(lambda x: len(x)==1)]
```

and you ends up with each element of the list being one of the dataframe you want, for example.

```
print (list_df [0])
      y    yh    x    xw       w  Nxt  group
2  2419  2716  490  2196  1704.0  492    2.0
3  2310  2373  492   794   302.0  886    2.0
5  2198  2261  497   791   299.0  886    2.0
1  2715  2847  501  1725  1224.0  492    2.0
```

or

```
print (list_df [-1])
      y    yh    x    xw       w   Nxt  group
0  2987  3129  347  2092  1735.0   501    0.0
7  1663  2180  375  1092   600.0  1323    1.0
```

I see you want a name for each one, but I think it will be easier to access them if they are in a list

Comment: Awesome... that's what i expected. Really thankful for understanding my problem and helping with correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have done the implementation of the problem from what I understood.

```
group = df.groupby("x").groups

def neighbour(temp):
    temp_final = []
    final = []
    for i in range(len(temp)):
        t = []
        for j in range(len(temp)):
            if abs(temp[i] - temp[j]) <= 20:
                t.append(temp[j])
            else:
                pass
        t = sorted(t)
        temp_final.append(t)

    temp_final = list(set(frozenset(sublist) for sublist in final))
    for i in range(len(temp_final)):
        u = []
        for item in temp_final[i]:
            u.append(item)
        final.append(u)

    return final

dataframes = {}
for i in range(len(val)):
    key_name = "dataframe_"+str(i)
    dg = pd.DataFrame()
    for item in val[i]:
        index = list(group[item])
        for i in range(len(index)):
            dg = dg.append(df.iloc[index[i]])

    dataframes[key_name] = dg
```

Please let me know in case of any misinterpretation.

```
dataframes

{'dataframe_0':      Nxt       w      x      xw       y      yh
5  886.0   299.0  497.0   791.0  2198.0  2261.0
2  492.0  1704.0  490.0  2196.0  2419.0  2716.0
3  886.0   302.0  492.0   794.0  2310.0  2373.0
1  492.0  1224.0  501.0  1725.0  2715.0  2847.0, 'dataframe_1':       Nxt
w      x      xw       y      yh
0   501.0  1735.0  357.0  2092.0  2987.0  3129.0
7  1323.0   600.0  375.0  1092.0  1663.0  2180.0, 'dataframe_2':      Nxt      
w      x      xw       y      yh
4  492.0  126.0  886.0  1012.0  2309.0  2370.0
6  492.0  124.0  886.0  1010.0  2197.0  2258.0}
```

Here is the output.

Comment: Thanks for your solution and efforts .... but i was more interested to get this from something inbuilt function instead of traditional way of looping....