# Is there a Pandas way to group dates that are less than 2 minutes apart in a dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

i would like to make a groupby on  my data to put together dates that are close. (less than 2 minutes)

Here an example of what i get

```
> datas = [['A', 51, 'id1', '2020-05-27 05:50:43.346'], ['A', 51, 'id2',
> '2020-05-27 05:51:08.347'], ['B', 45, 'id3', '2020-05-24
> 17:23:55.142'],['B', 45, 'id4', '2020-05-24 17:23:30.141'], ['C', 34,
> 'id5', '2020-05-23 17:31:10.341']]
> 
> df = pd.DataFrame(datas, columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'cold_id',
> 'dates'])
```

The 2 first rows have close dates, same for the 3th and 4th rows, 5th row is alone.

I would like to get something like this :

```
> datas = [['A', 51, 'id1 id2', 'date_1'], ['B', 45, 'id3 id4',
> 'date_2'], ['C', 34, 'id5', 'date_3']]
> 
> df = pd.DataFrame(datas, columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col_id',
> 'dates'])
```

Making it in a pythonic way is not that hard, but i have to make it on big dataframe, a pandas way using groupby method would be much efficient.

After apply a datetime method on the dates column i tried :

```
> df.groupby([df['dates'].dt.date]).agg(','.join)
```

but the .dt.date method gives a date every day and not every 2 minutes.

Do you have a solution ?

Thank you

Comment: Can I use `col1` and `col2` to grouping pairwise before compute the timedelta or it's based only on date whatever the value of other columns? In fact, is it possible `(A,51)` appears more than twice? And if there is 3  or more `dates` in an interval of 2 minutes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the output seems like we are trying to group `dates by 2 min freq` and `col1, col2`.

**Code**

```
df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df.dates)
df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='dates', freq='2 min'), 
            'col1', 'col2']).agg(','.join).reset_index().sort_values('col1').reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Output**

```
    dates             col1  col2    cold_id
0   2020-05-27 05:50:00 A   51      id1,id2
1   2020-05-24 17:22:00 B   45      id3,id4
2   2020-05-23 17:30:00 C   34      id5
```

Comment: This is exactly what i need, thank you, i should take a look to pd.Grouper

Answer (score 0):

Using only dates, this is what I did to classifiate your rows :

First of all, convert date to timestamp to compare them easily :

```
from datetime import datetime
import time

df["dates"] = df["dates"].apply(lambda x : int(time.mktime(datetime.strptime(x,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f").timetuple())))
```

Then, sort them by date :

```
df = df.sort_values("dates")
```

Finally, using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51541718/13055818), I create a column `group` in order to identify close dates. The first line add 1 into group column if dates are close enough (120 seconds in our case). The second line will fill in the column group to remove the NaN and assign groups :

```
df.loc[(df.dates.shift() < df.dates - 120),"group"] = 1
df['group'] = df['group'].cumsum().ffill().fillna(0)
```

This gives me :

```
  col1  col2 cold_id       dates  group
4    C    34     id5  1590247870   0.00
3    B    45     id4  1590333810   1.00
2    B    45     id3  1590333835   1.00
0    A    51     id1  1590551443   2.00
1    A    51     id2  1590551468   2.00
```

Now, to concatenate your cold_id, you groupby your groups and join the `cold_id` of each group by using [transform](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html):

```
df["cold_id"] = df.groupby(["group"],as_index=False)["cold_id"].transform(lambda x: ','.join(x))
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=["cold_id"])
```

This finally gives you this dataframe :

```
  col1  col2  cold_id       dates  group
4    C    34      id5  1590247870   0.00
3    B    45  id4,id3  1590333810   1.00
0    A    51  id1,id2  1590551443   2.00
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I realize that I am still a long way from knowing how to use pandas.